# ¿Hay un límite máximo de caracteres que se pueden enviar en un input de un formulario html?

Tags: java, html, html5, post

Tengo una situación, en la que por equis razones necesito enviar el `base64` de varias imágenes por medio de un input hidden.

El problema, como saben, es que el `base64` de los archivos puede ser súmamente largo, cientos de miles de caracteres; hay algún límite?

Obtengo el `base64` de las imágenes en un arreglo con `javascript` y `jquery`, luego hago un `JSON.stringify( ARREGLOBASE64 )`, mi intención es setear el resultado de esto en un input hidden y en el servidor convertir esto en un json y poder procesarlos.

Me preocupa el hecho de que puedan subirse muchas imágenes y el string que se vaya a enviar por el input hidden sea exageradamente grande.

¿Hay algún límite?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107999/how-many-characters-are-possible-in-an-input-field-in-html

Comment: @Lixus esa respuesta es cuando se "freezea", escribiendo caracteres en el input de texto. En esta pregunta no hay inputs de texto, él va a mandar todos esos caracteres en un input hidden

Comment: Todo input que no sea especificado su tipo se convierte en texto, no existe un input hidden, hidden es solo un atributo que se le da a cualquier tag de HTML para ocultarlo de la vista.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás haciendo el envío? ¿Es a un servicio propio o de un tercero?

Comment: Es obligatorio usar base64, puedes usar otro algoritmo de cifrado? si es asi prueba con un algoritmo de cifrado por deplazamiento como el ROT13 o XOR

Comment: Hola a todos, la info del formularios e procesará en el servidor mío. Todo es mío, nada es de terceros. 

@Crack81, sugieres que el base64 lo cifre para que (supongo) se haga más chica la longitud del string?

Comment: Ya vi esos cifrados, no son de ayuda, gracias igual.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada, no tiene nada que ver `maxchar` o atributos que cambien lo que el usuario pueda escribir.

Lo que te tiene que importar acá es el tamaño del request.

Si es un **GET**, los navegadores generalmente limitan el tamaño de estos (2kb aprox)

Si es un **POST**, los navegadores no lo limitan aunque en el servidor generalmente por defecto si se limitan.

Resumen: Supongo que lo haces con **POST**, solo estate atento a si el servidor limita el tamaño de  este y estará bien.

Comment: Bueno, una de las etiquetas de la publicación fue POST. Lo haré por post y pues veré cómo reacciona el server

Answer (score -1):

De acuerdo a la [especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), **no hay límite**, en teoría:

> `maxlength` = number [CN] When the type attribute has the value "text"
>   or "password", this attribute specifies the maximum number of
>   characters the user may enter. This number may exceed the specified
>   size, in which case the user agent should offer a scrolling mechanism.
>   **The default value for this attribute is an unlimited number**.
>
> ---
>
> Cuando el atributo `type` tiene el valor "`text`" o "`password`", este
>   atributo especifica el número máximo de caracteres que el usuario
>   puede ingresar. Este número puede exceder el tamaño especificado, en
>   cuyo caso el agente de usuario debe ofrecer un mecanismo de
>   desplazamiento. **El valor predeterminado para este atributo es un
>   número ilimitado**.

Según la [especificación de HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-apply), en los siguientes casos, *aplica* poner un límite:

- Campos de Texto
- Campos de búsqueda
- URLs
- Teléfonos
- Email
- Password

Pero, en tu caso, quizá haya otro elemento mejor para guardar grandes cantidades de texto, como [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/textarea), el cual puedes ocultar mediante CSS, tal como intentas hacer con el input, aunque, si revisan el código fuente del sitio, no serviría de nada (creo), ocultar el contenido, pero ese sería otro asunto.

Comment: le agregaria a esta respuesta colocar un estilo al text area tipo hidden para asi enviarlo sin problemas con el tamaño que desea

Comment: ¿Y qué diferencia hay entre usar un textarea y un input text?

Comment: @user2930137 Realmente, para el caso que planteas la diferencia tiene poca importancia: por **definición** los `textarea` se usan para textos largos, multilínea, pensando, claro está, en la presentación del texto, lo cual no interesa en tu caso. Aunque, leyendo más detenidamente tu pregunta, no sé si has emprendido un modelo de solución poco idóneo. ¿Por qué no envías esos datos al servidor como una respuesta JSON sin liarte con elementos de HTML? Algo así con un servicio REST o una respuesta API.

Comment: Porque sería mucho lío, no es un proyecto propio, es un proyecto que ya tiene la empresa donde trabajo en la cual se pidió un cambio. El sistema está en struts2 y he tenido mil y un problemas para poder enviarle archivos al servidor como se supone debería ser (un s:file y en el modelo declarar una variable File con sus getters y setters, además que no se puede usar multiple en un s:file en esta versión) así que no queda de otra que enviar la información del formulario (la que ya está) más la nueva información de las imágenes en base64.

Comment: Me hubiera encantado utilizar REST o SOAP, pero el servicio con el que se suben imágenes al servidor no está publicado en internet, es un servicio que está meramente en el servidor así que a fuerzas tiene que ser por ahí. Odio los proyectos realizados en el 2007 aprox heheh

Comment: @user2930137 no he explorado la posiblidad, pero imagino que se puede construir un servicio REST local sin mucha dificultad.

Comment: Técnicamente me dedico a hacer servicios rest y soap con Java xd El problema es que no se me da la oportunidad de publicar alguno en este proyecto, pues es un portal. Normalmente no se me pasa front end pero pues se ocupó y pudiera hacer un servicio que aceptara las imágenes y luego conectara al servicio ese que te digo que está en el server pero el problema es que no se me da dónde publicarlo xd

Comment: Por cierto, ya que tengo tu atención. ¿Cómo crees que sería mejor?
Enviar todo el string al servidor y allá convertirlo en json y luego en arreglo o generar tantos inputs como bases64 que tenga y enviarlos al server ya como un arreglo tal como lo dice esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element ?? qué opinas?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quisiste decir en tu penúltimo comentario. En cuanto a lo que preguntas en el último, lo que se suele usar es JSON, tanto para enviar como para recibir datos del servidor, por la ligereza de dicho formato y porque puedes enviar/recibir mediante JSON cualquier entidad de dato bien estructurada. Es así como funcionan las APIs, los servicios REST y servicios más modernos como Firebase. Luego, parseas el JSON en el destino final y lo muestras según las necesidades de la aplicación.

Comment: Y cómo le hago para enviar el objeto json por post en el envío del formulario?

Comment: @user2930137 Fíjate que te pregunta era con respecto a la máxima capacidad de datos que se podía tener en un input. He tratado de responder a esa cuestión. Talvez la pregunta ha ayudado a pensar que quizá debas implementar otro tipo de servicio para tu aplicación. Según las normas del sitio, cuando surgen nuevas preguntas es mejor plantearlas como nuevas. Entre otras cosas porque podrás obtener respuestas de varias personas, más rápido y de mejor calidad y no se conoce bien el contexto. Recomendaría que marques aquí la respuesta que solucionó el problema y formules una nueva.

Comment: Chale, google chrome se queda sin memoria ahahaha esto no va a funcionar así :'v tendré que ver alternativas a fuerzas

Comment: Cómo publico una pregunta que se basará únicamente en opiniones y no me la cierren?

Comment: @user2930137 _¿Cómo publico una pregunta que se basará únicamente en opiniones y no me la cierren?_, pues publicando una pregunta que no se base en opiniones. Es decir, la pregunta que hagas no tiene por qué basarse en opiniones y puedes, antes de plantearle buscar en el sitio a ver si no existen ya preguntas similares con soluciones dadas.

Comment: Pues realmente se basa en opiniones, era para encontrar alternativas de solución a mi problema, pero bueno

Comment: @user2930137 Si planteas el problema con claridad y lo que has intentando, no sería una pregunta basada en opiniones. Por otra parte, agradecería que, si es posible, revirtieras el voto negativo a mi respuesta. Se ha hecho un esfuerzo por responder al título de tu pregunta, el cual no ha sido valorado en absoluto.